# История поговорки "Орёл да Кромы — первые воры"

Tags: этимология, фразеология, история

**"Орёл да Кромы — первые воры".**

Поговорка кажется странной. Уж очень уничижительно  она звучит. Неужели не было в России более вороватых мест? Откуда пошло это присловье?

Answer (score 4):

Обычно подобные поговорки связывают с временами Смуты, поэтому я приведу в качестве ответа цитату из книги Льва Успенского "Загадки топонимики":

> Вряд ли следует думать, чтобы дореволюционные орловцы были менее чисты
>   на руку, чем их соседи туляки или куряне. Но вся страна помнила
>   рифмованную присказку:
>
> ОРЕЛ да КРОМЫ — первые воры,
>
> А ЛИВНЫ — всем ворам дивны,
>
> А ЕЛЕЦ — всем ворам отец,
>
> Да КАРАЧЕВ — на придачу…
>
> Помнила и хранила смутное подозрение, что, может быть, и нет дыма без
>   огня? Недаром же все так складно уложилось в присказку!
>
> Притом вполне возможно, что в далекой древности, когда складывалась
>   поговорка, самое слово «вор» имело еще не наше нынешнее, а иное,
>   старорусское значение. «Вор» в те времена могло означать «изменник
>   родины», «бунтовщик», «правонарушитель» в широком смысле — вообще
>   очень многое, а вовсе не «тать», не «тот, кто крадет». Вспомните
>   «Тушинского вора» — прямого врага московской власти. И вполне
>   возможно, что «первыми ворами» Орел да Кромы (то есть обитатели этих
>   мест) прослыли, еще когда города лежали на своей южной окраине
>   Московской Руси, когда само название «кромы» означало ее край, рубеж,
>   «кромку», когда за ними в «Диком поле» скрывались беглые мужики, когда
>   в самих их пределах могло находить поддержку и покрытие всякое
>   «воровство», то есть борьба с царской властью.

Answer (score 0):

Поговорка зародилась в Смутное время, когда Лжедмитрий с поляками собирались идти на Москву, они накапливали силы в Ельце и Кромах.

В те времена, слово "вор" означало "политический преступник", изменник.

Answer (score 0):

Добавлю для полноты. Вор - бунтовщик (а не просто "политический преступник"), а смысл поговорки несколько шире, к аллюзиям Смутного времени не сводится, хотя они, конечно, там на первом месте.

Вот более или менее подробная история тех событий, проливающая свет и на саму поговорку.

> Орёл да Кромы первые воры, Елец всем ворам отец, Ливны всем ворам
>   дивны, Дмитровцы воров не выдавцы, а Карачев на поддачу». Именно такая
>   поговорка в различных вариациях возникла во времена Смуты про города,
>   позднее объединённых в рамках Орловской губернии. При этом надо
>   понимать, что «ворами» в те далёкие времена называли не того кто крал
>   кошельки и имущество, а людей покушавшихся на государственную власть,
>   бунтовщиков. Воры в современном значении этого слова прозывались
>   «татями». Такое первенство в коллаборационизме орловчанам
>   приписывается из-за необычайной отзывчивости местных жителей ко всяким
>   проходимцам и самозванцам, заполонивших в те времена территорию
>   Московского государства. События же под Кромами в начале XVII века
>   способствовали падению династии Годуновых и восхождению на престол
>   Лжедмитрия I.